# Getting jdbcTemplate null in Spring Junit test case

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, junit4

I am writing junit test case for spring 3 restful services. When I am trying to execute it as junit, i am getting JdbcTemplate as null. I am not sure where I did the mistake. Please help me to get out of this...

LoginServiceImpl.java file,

```
private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Autowired
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    jdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    System.out.println("--------------"+jdbcTemplate.toString());
}

private static Map<String, AuthToken> tokenHash = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, AuthToken>();

private static String authTokenDetailsSql = "select * from authtoken where token = :token";

@Override
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ServiceBean newAccount(@RequestBody Registration registration) {
    String newAccountSql = "INSERT INTO account (email,password,name) VALUES (:email,:password,:name)";
    ServiceDataBean<AuthToken> retBean = new ServiceDataBean<AuthToken>();
    try {
        System.out.println("register service calling.....");
        MapSqlParameterSource namedParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        namedParameters.addValue("email", registration.getEmail());
        messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        byte[] md5 = new byte[64];
        messageDigest.update(registration.getPassword().getBytes("iso-8859-1"), 0, registration.getPassword().length());
        md5 = messageDigest.digest();
        namedParameters.addValue("password", convertedToHex(md5));
        namedParameters.addValue("name", registration.getName());
        GeneratedKeyHolder generatedKeyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();

        // TODO what to do with the updInt also check it's not -1
        int updInt = jdbcTemplate.update(newAccountSql, namedParameters, generatedKeyHolder);
        long accountId = (Long) generatedKeyHolder.getKeys().get("GENERATED_KEY");
        registration.getDevice().setOwner(registration.getId());
        fotoframz.register(registration.getDevice());
        Login login = new Login();
        login.setEmail(registration.getEmail());
        login.setPassword(registration.getPassword());
        login.setDevice(registration.getDevice());
        retBean = (ServiceDataBean<AuthToken>) this.login(login);
        System.out.println("form register");
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        retBean.setStatusCode("001");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return retBean;
}
```

I am getting jdbctemplate=null at `int updInt = jdbcTemplate.update(newAccountSql, namedParameters, generatedKeyHolder);`

my applicationContext-test.xml file is in src/test/resources folder..applicationContext-test.xml file

```
<context:component-scan base-package="net.mss.ff.services" />       
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/app.properties" />

<!-- <task:annotation-driven /> -->
<context:annotation-config />
<!-- <import resource="apicontroller_v1-servlet.xml"/>
<import resource="applicationContext.xml"/> -->

<bean id="photoService" class="net.mss.ff.services.core.api.impl.PhotoServiceImpl">
    <property name="rootStorageFolder" value="${storage.root}" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:url="${jdbc.url}" p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" />
```

### LoginServiceImplTest

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/applicationContext-test.xml"})
public class LoginServiceImplTest {

LoginServiceImpl loginServiceObj = new LoginServiceImpl();
Device deviceMock;

@Autowired
private Fotoframz fotoframz;

/*private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Autowired
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    jdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}*/

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    //loginServiceObj = new LoginServiceImpl();
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception{

}

/**
 * Test method for {@link net.mss.ff.services.core.api.impl.LoginServiceImpl#newAccount(net.mss.ff.services.core.beans.Registration)}.
 */
@Test
public void testNewAccount() {
    Registration mockRegObj = new Registration();
    deviceMock = new Device();
    deviceMock.setActive(false);
    deviceMock.setHeight(45);
    //deviceMock.setId(4568);
    deviceMock.setName("Android");
    deviceMock.setOwner(1111);
    deviceMock.setPlatform("Windows NT");
    deviceMock.setUuid("522601");
    deviceMock.setVersion("1.0");
    deviceMock.setWidth(76);
    mockRegObj.setEmail("bbb@gmail.com");
    /*mockRegObj.setId(399);*/
    mockRegObj.setName("bbb");
    mockRegObj.setPassword("BBB");
    mockRegObj.setDevice(deviceMock);
    loginServiceObj.newAccount(mockRegObj);

    //assertEquals("New Account Creation", "", "");
}
```

}
anything needs to modify in test class, please let me know..

Comment: show us your test code, it seems that your junit is not initialising your spring bean xml. If jdbctemplate is null, it means your `setDatasource` method is not getting invoked.

Comment: according to your unit test class, **LoginServiceImpl loginServiceObj = new LoginServiceImpl();** won't resolve dependencies. You need some thing like @Autowired  LoginServiceImpl loginServiceObj ; in your unit test class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your test the `LoginServiceImpl loginServiceObj = new LoginServiceImpl();`
is not instantiated by spring, thus no annaotions will be applied. You need to autowire it, or inject it some other way. Spring 3.2 makes this kinda thing super easy and nice to use.

The rest of my answer is still good adivce :
You have not declared or instantiated the jdbctemplate in your java code. And you have not defined it in your xml file.

You need this

```
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dateSource"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

and then this as instance variable (assuming your using annoations)

```
   @Resource(name = "jdbcTemplate")
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```

Comment: Thanks for your immediate reply..Normal application is working fine, but in the case of junit only i am getting jdbctemplate as null..

Comment: I guess @user1441341 just doesn't include it  in the code snippet, otherwise he will get compile error.

Comment: @user1441341 you are using new keyword to create th ejdbc template, don;t do that. Also, put your data access somewhere else other than the controller. I recommed sprign 3.2 it makes testing easier.

Comment: we are using spring 3.1.0.RELEASE version.

Comment: @NimChimpsky,Thank you very much. It is a small thing, but I didnt find it..:)

Answer (score 1):

As @NimChimpsky mentioned you need to define your `jdbcTemplate` in your bean xml file and then in your instance variable you can also do.

```
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```